# Not able to Modify CIDR block after creating VPC

Tags: alibaba-cloud

After creating VPC using standard private IP address and their subnets in Alibaba Cloud VPC.

> The standard IP address ranges include 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12,
>   192.168.0.0/16 and the default is 172.16.0.0/12.

I am not able to modify CIDR Block

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the vpc cidr block after creation.

See the documentation link https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/65430.htm

You need to create the new VPC with new CIDR range.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the VPC you cannot modify the CIDR Block. If you want to modify the CIDR range then the optimal way is to create the new VPC with desired CIDR Range.

You can confirm the same on the [Alibaba official documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/65430.htm) as well